# VB.NET something like FindControl but to create a control

Tags: vb.net

I need to create a control on a web page to display a grid. I have done something like this:

```
Dim cell As System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl
cell = page.Master.FindControl("footer")
```

but this it's only getting this control and it gets replaced by whatever I put on it.

I want to create a whole new control but I have no idea how to do it. I've been searching on Microsoft website for a while now and found nothing that worked for me.

Comment: Create a [PlaceHolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder.aspx) control on your page and then `placeholder.Controls.Add(YourGridControl)`

Comment: I'm working with a framework so i have almost everything created, and I don't need to create the placeholder because it's already created in page.master.findcontrol(content), so I though that page.master.findcontrol(content).Controls.Add(grid), would work, but it does not. I have a Dim grid as webcontrollib.Nossogrid. That's the controller for the grid...